# How to calculate slow-start threshold

Tags: tcp

So far I observed in Ubuntu 18.04 the TCP's slow start threshold(ssthresh) shows 18, looks it seems default value. Can any one please let me know how the server calculates this value or reading it somewhere else in config. Is it possible to tune it? TIA.